# How can I attach event to a tag which is in string form?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm creating html on runtime like this:

```
var myVar = "<div id='abc'>some clickable text</div>"
```

Now, I want to attach some event, say onclick, to this div. How can I do that on next line? I'll add this to DOM later.

PS: I've to accomplish this without using JQuery.

Comment: You need to add it to them dom before you can attach an event to it. Unless you add an onclick attribute in the text. Until a dom object is created this is still just a piece of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use this technique: attach event to the `document.body`. Then if the event target is not the needed div than just do nothing. It is the same techinque jquery uses for its `live` function:

```
// crossbrowser event attachment function
function listen(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
    }
    else if (elem.attachEvent) {
        var r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
        return r;
    }
    else window.alert('I\'m sorry Dave, I\'m afraid I can\'t do that.');
}

// this is an analog of the jquery.live
var assignLiveEvent = function(id, evnt, callback) {
    var handler = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.target = e.target || e.srcElement;

        if (e.target.id == id) {
            //your code here
            callback(e);
        }
    };

    listen(evnt, document.body, handler);
};

var myVar = "<div id='abc'>some clickable text</div>";

assignLiveEvent("abc", "click", function(e) {
    //your code here
});

// now you can add your div to DOM even after event handler assignation
```

### Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cxXcC/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building your div as a string, you'll want to use [document.createElement('div')](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/createElement). This way you will have a real dom object, and can get and set it's propeties, including `onClick`

Answer (score 1):

Try building the div as a DOM element first.

```
var myVar = document.createElement("div"),
    parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent_div");

parentDiv.appendChild(myVar);
myVar.innerHTML = "some clickable text";
if(myVar.addEventListener){
    myVar.addEventListener("click", clickFn, false);
}
else if(myVar.attachEvent){
    myVar.attachEvent("onclick", clickFn);
}
else{
    myVar.onclick = clickFn;
}
```

The addEventListener method is standard, but not every browser plays nice with the standard.

EDIT: As mentioned, an element must be added to the DOM first.

Answer (score 1):

Will this help? Since you dynamically generate it, you know the control id of the DIV.

```
document.getElementbyId('abc').onClick = foo;
function foo()
{
alert("All your impl to go here");
}
```

Comment: please declare the function before attributing the onClick. and your answer is incomplete

Comment: function declarations can be referenced out of sequence as shown, but it's true that the answer is incomplete because it doesn't show how to create any elements.

Answer (score 0):

Brian Glaz is totally right but, if for some reason, you really need to do it this way, you have two options:

you can only add events to something that is already in the DOM, using pure javascript, so you would have to include it in the html like:

```
document.body.innerHTML += myVar;
```

and then, attach the event with

```
document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener('click', function(e){
   //your code
}, 1);
```

With jQuery, you could use .live() to attach events to elements that are not yet present in the DOM:

```
 $('#abc').live('click', function(e){
    //your code here
 });
```

so you could add the div later...

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML += myVar;` is very destructive, as it destroys the entire DOM and then rebuilds it with the new content. There are other ways to build new elements from a string of HTML markup.

Comment: " but, if for some reason, you really need to do it this way, you have two options:"... and i used body as a container, because i got no more references...

Comment: *"you would have to include it in the html like... `document.body.innerHTML...`"* If you're suggesting that jQuery is the only other option, then that's even worse, and I guarantee that they don't do `innerHTML += ...`.

Comment: Isn't live deprecated? I'm trying to use "on" but that's not working as expected