# Unable to attach event to an element in contextual fragment

Tags: javascript, events

I tried to attach an event to an element in a contextual fragment and then appended this element to body. But the event doesn't get attached.

```
var range = document.createRange();
var listE1 = "<div>Hello World</div>"
range.selectNode(document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0));
var element = range.createContextualFragment(listEl);

element.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("hello");
}, true);

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

After appending this element to body, the div doesn't have any event at all

Comment: try attaching the event after you add it to they body perhaps?

Comment: if i've so many elements to attach event (say i'm using loop), then it would be costly to attach event after appending to dom right?

Comment: if you are adding many elements to the dom it is costly anyway. Besides the you can't attach events before they are in the dom unless you use the specific event attribute on the element. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117607/how-can-i-attach-event-to-a-tag-which-is-in-string-form for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon here after looking for the same answer and I know this is a very old question hope this helps or points to a better direction.

The `range.createContextualFragment(listEl);` returns a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). In a nutshell a DocumentFragment is minimalized  DOM object. It doesn't have an attachEventListener.

If you want you can either use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) or use [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Here's an example of how you can use DOMParser

```
let listE1 = "<div>Hello World</div>"
let element = new DOMParser().parseFromString(listE1 , 'text/html').documentElement;
element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("hello");
}, true);

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

only a lot of little mistake, the code should run right easy: 
we should add the fragment to document, then add the event listener

```js
var range = document.createRange();
var listE1 = "<div id='hello'>Hello World</div>"
range.selectNode(document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0));
var element = range.createContextualFragment(listE1); // listel -> liste1
document.body.appendChild(element); // should add to document first
document.querySelector("div#hello").addEventListener("click", function() { // element->document
  alert("hello");
}, true);
```